# Update data of one column after comparing data of another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 2 columns

```
NAME     SYNONYM
----------------
A        ALPHA            
B        ALPHA             
B        BITA                 
C        GAMA             
D        DELTA             
E        BITA
```

I am looking for a SQL query that will check column `SYNONYM`. If it finds the same `SYNONYM`, for example it finds `ALPHA` in second row which is the same with row 1 it will change B and make it A. The change of B will take place everywhere in column `NAME`, not only in one row.

```
NAME     SYNONYM  
----------------
A        ALPHA            
A        ALPHA             
A        BITA                 
C        GAMA             
D        DELTA             
A        BITA
```

If it is difficult to alter the column `NAME` we could add a new column like this

```
NAME    SYNONYM       NEW 
----------------------------
A        ALPHA          1
B        ALPHA          1
B        BITA           1
C        GAMA           2
D        DELTA          3
E        BITA           1
```

Comment: I honestly don't understand the problem statement. I think you need to 1) use the formatting tools, and 2) show us the before and after at the very least.  I really don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please don't use all-capitals in your question title, as it is perceived as shouting/generally rude.

Comment: What database? SQL Server? MySQL?

Comment: This is essentially recursive which sql does not handle very well. It is going to be difficult to do.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** This type of query is not possible in straight MySQL if its supposed to be a dynamic query... MySQL **does not** support recursive queries.. however if you know the column you would like to update then you can do this query in a roundabout way. 
So if there are some columns you would like to update you can do it like this and it'll do exactly what you're asking for..

**EDIT:**

if you use user defined variables you could walk through the table like so:

```
SET @A := (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM example_table ORDER BY name LIMIT 0,1);

UPDATE example_table et,
(
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT synonym
    FROM example_table
    WHERE name IN 
    (
        SELECT 
            DISTINCT name
        FROM example_table
        WHERE synonym IN 
        (
            SELECT 
                DISTINCT synonym
            FROM example_table
            WHERE name = @A
        )
    )
) t 
SET et.name = @A WHERE et.synonym = t.synonym;
```

all you have to do is increment the 0 in the SET @A statement.. LIMIT 0,1... LIMIT 1,1.... that will give you a new distinct name each time that you can execute the update on. Hope that helps